# Why did Maverick Records ask Muse to remove falsetto?

Tags: rock, recording, backstory, muse

*Origin of Symmetry* was an album made by alt-rock band Muse in 2001.

Maverick Records, the planned publisher before release, had asked that some songs be recorded again without lead singer Matthew Bellamy’s famous falsetto from them.

Why was this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They would 'discourage radio play' according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_Symmetry)

As it turned out, instead it discouraged Muse… & they left the label.

> Origin of Symmetry was to be released in the US on the 28th August 2001 but the release was cancelled after Muse left Maverick Records, who previously released Showbiz in the United States. The record label asked the band to remove the falsetto vocals for the album's release, claiming that their presence would discourage radio play. Muse's refusal saw them part ways with the label, meaning that the album was not released in the US until 2005.